# How to add a JS to my wordpress website

Tags: javascript, wordpress

So I recently bought a JS file from someone and I have a wordpress website. The script file contains a css folder, a script folder, and a font folder. Where should I upload this to? Publid_html? And how do I implement it to my website? (Its made with bootstrap)

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make folders within the THEME folder.

So basically

-YOURTHEME(main theme folder)

css(folder)
js(folder)
Img(folder)
index.php(file)

Etc.

as for where to call it  from: put this code in your functions.php file.

```
function YOURTHEME_script_enqueue() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), true )
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 'all');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blackmass_script_enqueue');
```

here you can add the scripts and wordpress will place them in the HEAD or FOOT locations depending on the SCRIPT/STYLE at the begining of the argument, and the ALL/TRUE functions at the end of the argument.

as for the two index.php files one in scripts folder, and one in main theme folder. you only need the one thats in the themes folder. you can delete the other one.

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer. Im just confused as to how I can display the actual script on the website that I need it on. The script is basicly a form where one can choose different options and I would like to display it on a specific page. Where can I do this? Thank you so much, I will definately use your answer and upvote you =)

Comment: First of all, if the answer helped, please tick it as the answer.

Comment: the form i am assuming is html/css, this can be placed in any of the pages within wordpress, once the CSS files and SCRIPT files are listed in the Function.php file, it will place them in the html body for you automatically.
please give some more info on what you would like to do, happy to help but its the question now is pretty broad

Comment: The script your talking about is a LINK/SCRIPT inside the head tag? or code that is put inside that specific page?

Comment: The script is basicly just HTML/CSS with bootstrap where there is a drop down menu and you can select different values changing the numbers. I have a specific page I want to display this form on, how can I do this? Thank you very much, ticked it as an answer =)

Comment: OK, you need to put the HTML in the page you want it displayed on. Then you need to link the CSS style sheet to the project, as per my answer above. one that is done, you just need to put <?php get_header(); ?> at the top of the "page" you want the CSS file to action on. Wordpress places the css files that have been placed in functions.php and shares it to whatever page has the get_header argument in it.

Comment: When putting the script enqueue into my function php, my whole website dashboard crashed saying: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'wp_enqueue_style' (T_STRING)

Comment: I added this: function appointment_script_enqueue() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrapjs', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js', array(), true )
wp_enqueue_style('bootstrapstyle', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), 'all');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'blackmass_script_enqueue');

Answer (score 0):

The best implementation of those files would be root/wp-content/themes/{your-custom-theme}/assets

So under assets you can put like css,js,fonts,images
and make it link from functions.php

Comment: Alright Ill try that. If I just want to put it on one specific page, how do I do that?

Comment: where is wordpress function if(is_page('home'))  wp_enqueue_script()//here this is home page is_page('about') its about page wp_enqueue_script()// herere

Comment: In my script folder I also have a index.php file, and in my themes folder there is also one. What should I do / Where should I place it? Thanks for the help. If it works ill give you the answer and an upvote =)

Answer (score 0):

You must read the WP Codex about this, but here an quick example:
With [get_stylesheet_directory_uri()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) function you can grab link to your current theme folder `(themes/your-theme-name/)` for example.

In this folder you can create your own structure, but best practice is to have diffrent folders for js/, css/, images/ etc.

When you decide where you want to put your `.js` and `.css` files then you must include them with [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [wp_enqueue_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) functions using  `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook like this:

```
function my_scripts_include() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'my-style-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/my-css-file.css', []  );
   wp_enqueue_script( 'my-script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-script.js', array('my-script-depends-from-this-script'), '1.0.0', true );
   if ( some_logic ) {
      wp_enqueue_script('my-other-script' .... );
   }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_include' );
```

You must put this code in your theme `functions.php` file.

But really, there have so many tutorials about WP, you must read some to understand better this process.